# Putting global.d.ts inside my src folder gives me problems with watch of Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia, typescript-typings

I created a `global.d.ts` file inside my `src` folder.

global.d.ts

```
interface Foo {

}
```

Then I used that type in one of my TypeScript file

```
const x: Foo = {};
```

No errors in my Editor. In my terminal `au run` works without problems. After that, if I modified my code (even adding a space and save) changes are detected and compilation is triggered. Then I got compile errors:

```
Starting 'buildTypeScript'...
src\eskimo-scripts.ts(21,18): error TS2339: Property 'Foo' does not exist.
TypeScript: 1 semantic error
TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[12:45:00] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: TypeScript: Compilation failed
Finished 'buildTypeScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
INFO [Bundler] Tracing files ...
```

BUT if I moved the `global.d.ts` file from `src` folder into `custom_typings` folder. I don't have that kind of problem. It seems Aurelia don't like I put my `...d.ts` file inside my `src` folder.

I'm new to using type definitions so I thought it was okay to place `global.d.ts` inside my `src` folder but maybe I got wrong.

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "src"
},
"include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
],
"atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
}
}
```

**EDIT**

After testing different things, it seems I have to add line below on top of my file

```
/// <reference path="global.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Are you importing the `Foo` interface?

Comment: If I import my type definitions like this  `import { Foo } from './foo.d'; ` it works.